# What is an adverb for "via the written word"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I can say something is 'verbally delivered'. How would I say it is 'delivered via the written word', but with an adverb? E.g. something like 'literally delivered', as in, "using letters" - but that is an odd use of the term relying more on the etymology than the understood meaning of the word.

Comment: I'm not aware of a single adverb which conveys this meaning. I would say **"in writing"** if I wanted something to be communicated in the way you describe.

Comment: If one were writing, one could simply write "ibidem". If one were speaking, one should in any event use a verb indicating writing and not speaking.

Comment: @JohnLawler: How would `ibidem` be used? How would I convey the phrase "The information was delivered in writing" using `ibidem`?

Comment: My mistake. What you want is [sic], immediately after the **exact** (spelled and punctuated, every jot and tittle exactly the same as the original) quote. E.g: "She capturred the Wookiee" [sic]. But only for written quotation, in quotation marks,  of originally written text.

Comment: There's also the pair _litteratim_ 'letter by letter' (for written text only) and _verbatim_ 'word for word', which can apply to either written or spoken (but not to mistakes in spelling, etc).

Comment: @JohnLawler: I think you misunderstood my intent. Say I want to tell somebody a story. I can tell it to them **verbally**, or **in writing**. I'm asking - is there an adverb I can use instead of **in writing**?

Comment: @Claudiu- what's wrong with saying "*in writing*" or "*in written form*"?

Comment: @Jim: it's more aesthetically pleasing to me to use parallel forms in my sentences

Comment: Well, that's a reasonable aim in many languages, but in English, it's much harder to attain. Frost couldn't even keep up _terza rima_ for more than 4 verses, while Dante went on and on for thousands.

Comment: @JohnLawler: true, but it can't hurt to try - and it looks like i've succeeded in this case thanks to the community here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If OP really wants a one-word adverb, perhaps [orthographically](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22not%20help%20being%20overcome%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22communicate%20orthographically%22&oq=%22communicate%20orthographically%22&gs_l=serp.3...64476.66844.2.67802.12.12.0.0.0.1.81.688.12.12.0...0.0...1c.1.14.psy-ab.KYa-8laCgn0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47008514,d.d2k&fp=ef60e202bc9044c1&biw=1269&bih=865). That link contains several written instances of *"communicate orthographically"*, with presumably the intended sense...

> [**orthography**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/orthography) *- the representation of the sounds of a language by written or printed symbols*.

Comment: awesome! Just what I was looking for. "The information is the same be it delivered verbally or orthographically."

Comment: oh apparently this is a dupe, and **textually** is the answer for the other question, which I think I like more.